# Linear regression containing Nans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm working on a model which will predict a number from others opinion. For this i will use Linear Regression from Sklearn.

For example, i have 5 agents from witch i collect data over time of theirs last changes in each iteration, if they didn't insert it yet, data contains `Nan`, till their first change. Data looks something like this:

```
   a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   target
1  nan  nan  nan  nan  3     4.5
2  4    nan  nan  nan  3     4.5
3  4    5    nan  nan  3     4.5
4  4    5    5    nan  3     4.5
5  4    5    5    4    3     4.5
6  5    5    5    4    3     4.5
```

So in each iteration/change i want to predict end number. As we know linear regression doesn't allow you to have `an = Nan's` in data. I replace them with `an = 0`, witch doesn't ruin answer, because formula of linear regression is: `result = a1*w1 + a2*w2 + ... + an*wn + c`.

Current questions i have at the moment:

Does my solution somehow effects on fit? Is there any better solution for my problem? Should i learn my model only with full data than use it with current solution?

Comment: It will try to find a coefficient for a1=0 that minimizes the loss function. You will not use that coefficient when a1 is null but you will use it when it's not. So it sure will affect your results. That said, you should ask this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Setting nan's to 0 and training a linear regression to find coefficients for each of the variables is fine depending on the use case.

Why?

You are essentialy training the model and telling it that for many rows - the importance of variable a1 ,a2 , etc (when the value is nan and set to 0).

If the NAN's are because of data not being filled in yet, then setting them to 0 and training your model is wrong. It's better to train your model after all the data has been entered (atleast for all the agents who have entered some data) This can later be used to predict for new agents. Else , your coefficients will be over fit for 0's(NAN's) if many agents have not yet entered in their data.

Based on the end target(which is a continuous variable) , linear regression is a good approach to go by.